# Strengths and weaknesses of JIT compilers for Python

Tags: python, compiler-construction, project

I'm currently aware of the following Python JIT compilers: Psyco, PyPy and Unladen Swallow.

Basically, I'd like to ask for your personal experiences on the strengths and weaknesses of these compilers - and if there are any others worth looking into.

Thanks in advance,

Az

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Have you experimented with each of those projects? If not, I would recommend trying that. If so, then do you have any specific questions? We can't decide which is the best *for you*.

Comment: I would love to, but I'm on a deadline and my supervisor isn't budging on an extension. So, if you can recommend a good starting point I'd really appreciate that. Or, even the easiest to start with would be good. I can probably update once I get more information then.

Comment: I'm not sure that *any* of those projects are suitable for production use at this time. Have you considered [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)?

Comment: @GregHewgill: AFAIK py2exe does not do a JIT/AOT compilation. It just bundles vm and code in the same file, so the perf depends on the underlying python implementation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Christian Perone has an excellent [article](http://blog.christianperone.com/?p=1189) from just a few days ago where he claims (with supporting benchmark data) that `PyPy` is now the fastest, running the benchmark in 145 seconds vs 300 for Unladen Swallow and 374 for CPython (Psyco doesn't help, actually PsycoV2 slows the benchmark down to 434 seconds), 557 for Jython -- see the URL I just gave for all details.

Of course, you'd need to confirm this on a wide range of benchmarks, but it sure seems credible and very interesting.  Pypy has the largest team working on it (and has had for many years, including several years with generous monetary support from European Union research grants), which is why it's quite credible that it's now "fully in gear" and ready for prime time!-)

Comment: wow, good update! interesting to see JIT performance improves it over CPython, I will start testing it too :)

Comment: there're some negative results in comments. Did you try PyPy on your own project? Can you compare it to CPython performance?

Comment: PyPy is nice, I just wish they supported Py3K, not forcing a choice between fast Python 2.x and slow Python 3.x

Answer (score 1):

Some other tools you might investigate to speed up python are

- Cython, which requires type specification of all variables in the relevant method and then statically compiles the method
- Numba, which requires LLVM but is JIT (methods must be decorated with argument types for compilation to occur).

Comment: jnnnnn when you are compiling in numba, do you have to manually configure the 'ast' llvm before hand? I've been trying to get it to work, but i keep ending in the same spot (Key Error <class 'ast.In'>) So i figured it was something to do with the LLVM itself.